# How can I add defined parameter to (NEXT VALUE FOR) command?

Tags: sql-server, sequence

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION sso.FINDSEQVALUE
    (@sequence_text text)  
RETURNS int   
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @value int;
    DECLARE @sequence_value nvarchar(150);  

    SELECT @sequence_value = CAST(@sequence_text AS nvarchar(150));
    SELECT @value = NEXT VALUE FOR @sequence_value;

    RETURN @value;  
END;
```

I have a problem. I have created a function on SQL Server and I defined the parameter as you can see. But I cannot add the this command `@sequence_value` after `NEXT VALUE FOR` command and I am getting an error.

> Incorrect syntax near '@sequence_value'

Somebody can say that "You can use (SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [SEQUENCE])". But I need this function because of there are two different database on my project. I need same function for databases. In addition function parameter need to be text.
What should I do?

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Like most SQL, its static, therefore you can't use a variable as the sequence name. If you need to do this use dynamic SQL. And therefore you cannot do it in a function, and instead must do it in a Stored Procedure. Really you try and avoid this sort of generic function... SQL is not intended for this.

Comment: You can't. You would have to **safely**, inject, the value in a dynamic statement. That's **safely**. Did I mention do it **safely**?

Comment: Also, to add to what @marc_s has stated, the data type for object names is `sysname`, a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`.

Comment: Also, as you would require dynamic SQL, it is therefore impossible to do it on a `FUNCTION`. I suspect what we have here is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: What is the other database? Can you use a table with an int identity(1,1) in SQL-Server and the equivalent in the other DB?

Comment: Other database is postgresql.